# How many ways are there to deal 13 cards from a deck to 4 players s.t. none receive all hearts?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Out of a 52 card deck, how many ways can we deal 13 cards to four players and none of them receive a hand of all hearts?

My approach thus far has been to take the total number of ways to deal each player a 13-card hand, that is 
$${52 \choose 13} \cdot {39 \choose 13} \cdot {26 \choose 13}$$ 
and subtract the number of ways that you could have a hand of all hearts at each step (which I believe is just one?).

Is this intuition correct? Any ideas on how to proceed? I'm very new to combinatorics/discrete math and would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: There's only one way for any given player to have all hearts, but the others could have any combination of cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The number of ways that the "first" player has a hand of all hearts is
$${39 \choose 13} \cdot {26 \choose 13}$$

Comment: Right, this makes sense. And I understand the comment from @Théophile, I suppose I can figure out the # ways each player can get all hearts, then subtract that from the total # ways to deal all cards. Thank you! :)